# Obtaining a reference to a function in a promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise like so...

```
const promise = fetch(url)
  .then(() => { console.log(1) })
  .then(() => { console.log(2) })
  .catch(() => {});
```

Is it possible to get a reference to the function that prints out 1?

EDIT: Further clarification: the variable `promise` is provided to me so I can't actually alter it. I can only call things on it.

Comment: At what point do you want to access the reference?

Comment: at the earliest point possible

Comment: I think the answer is no unless you declare the functions. What's the use case?

Comment: @JaromandaX That would be altering the promise.

Comment: have you tried binding the function `.bind(Scope Refrence)` which is most liekly `this`

Comment: after the clarification ... with a promise, the only thing you can "call on it" is `.then` and `.catch` and perhaps `.finally` (depending on implementation)

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess the answer is no then - I'm willing to accept an answer.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: https://github.com/bevacqua/promisees How does this do it. It can read promises and get access to the functions inside it.

Comment: @Ogen: I would guess it replaces `Promise` with a custom implementation. What do you need to do with the function?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question and comments, the answer is no. Credit to all the commenters ;)